# Elliptic Curve over a Finite Field, Adding Graphically

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I use Mathematica to add two points graphically on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 8$ over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. Specifically, I'd like to illustrate $(1,8)+(2,10)=(1,5)=(1,-8)$, but on first glance, $(2,3)=(2,-10)$ could also be a solution, because there are no other points of intersection on the line through $(1,8)$ and $(2,10)$.

$(1,5)$ is the correct solution because the equation to solve the addition algebraically, 
$$
(8+2(x-1))^2 = x^3 + 3x + 8
$$
factors
$$
12(x+11)(x+12)^2
$$
so $x=1$ is the third root (in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$).

**Question:** How can I recognize this double root if I interpret the addition geometrically by drawing a line through the points to be added in $\mathbb{F}_{13}^2$?

Comment: If you mean when drawing your line and the lattice points of $\Bbb{Z}^2$ and showing the intersection points and checking which ones have $\bmod p$ reduction on the curve, then you can find an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{R}^2$ containing your two points (and whose equation reduces $\bmod p$ to your original one), the double point in $\Bbb{R}^2$ can be seen by continuity, and it stays a double point in $\Bbb{F}_p^2$

Comment: Thanks! I'm already doing the (mod p) reduction on my line (drawn continuously; it wraps around when it gets to the "edge"). I plotted the individual points of the elliptic curve and I'm basically checking for which points get hit by my line.

Comment: Your two points $\in \Bbb{Z}^2$ are on the elliptic curve $C:y^2=x^3+3x+8 + 13(4 + 2(x-1)) $ that you can draw in $\Bbb{R}^2$ to show the line has a double intersection with $C$ at $(1,8)$

Comment: I have been present at at least one lecture where the speaker (in crypto) wanted to similarly visualize an elliptic curve over a prime field. IIRC he skipped the case requiring tangents. It is taxing to visualize over fields other than reals. Hence I went along with reuns' idea. Pictures created by Mathematica. Ping me, if you have problems reproducing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $(1,8)=(1,-5)$ and $(2,10)=(2,-3)$ I used reuns' idea, switched to the curve
$$y^2=x^3-23x+47,$$
(observe that the coefficients are congruent to those of the original), and produced the following image. The red line is connecting $(1,-5)$ and $(2,-3)$, both now on the curve.

[image]

You see that due to the relative proximity of the points $(1,-5)$ and $(2,-3)$ on the red line, it is a bit taxing to "see" that this line is actually a tangent to the elliptic curve at the first point. Zooming in does reveal that at the second point there is no tangency.

[image]

If your audience has been exposed to the implicit function theorem, you can explain how this (real) variant of the curve has a tangent of slope
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x_0^2-23}{2y_0}=\frac{11}6
$$
at the point $(x_0,y_0)=(2,-3)$. Very close to the slope $m=2$ of the red line, explaining the difficulty.

Unfortunately this visualization is probably not as clear as you might want.

Comment: Selecting the variant $y^2=x^3+29x+34$ thru the points $(1,8)$ and $(2,10)$ is actually a bit worse. The tangent at the latter point has then slope $41/20$, even close to the slope of the secant than here. May be you should use a different curve/ other points?

Comment: This is pretty and quite intuitive...in hindsight. I didn't think of cooking up a curve that is congruent $(\mod 13)$ to mine *and* contains the two points I want in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thanks!

Comment: Teaching ECs over a finite field is a bit taxing for this reason. Ultimately you need to justify things with algebra alone, but visualization is otherwise such a great aid.