# Do the solutions to an elliptic curve over a finite field correspond to solutions over the reals?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

In cryptography, we often deal with elliptic curves defined over a finite field, such as the integers modulo a large prime *p*. My mental intuition for what this does to the graph of the elliptic curve is that the x- and y-axes “wrap around” at 0 and *p* and then we consider only points that have exact integer coordinates. To illustrate, I have plotted a graph of $y^2 = x^3 - 3x + 3$ below “modulo” 13 (for a naïve translation of the $\operatorname{mod}$ operation to $\mathbb R$, which I will denote $\mathbb R_{13}$ in what is probably a horrible abuse of notation—I am not a mathematician). The graph plots *x* from -2.1 to 52.

I have also plotted the actual solutions to the curve equation in GF(13) for comparison. Only some of the points are intersected by the line of the graph over $\mathbb R_{13}$. My intuition is that if I extended the graph over $\mathbb R_{13}$ far enough it would eventually intersect all of the points in GF(13) and that there would be no other solutions where *x* and *y* are both integers. Is this intuition correct, or does the definition of square-roots in a finite fields differ sufficiently from that in the reals that this intuition is misleading?

[[image: The elliptic curve <span class=]$y^2 = x^3 - 3x + 3 drawn wrapping around at 13, with points of solutions in GF(13) also drawn.$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLLkd.jpg)

Comment: Your question is unclear, the point $(0,4)$ in $y^2=x^3-3x+3 \subset \Bbb{F}_{13}\times \Bbb{F}_{13}$ comes from the point $(0,4)\in  y^2=x^3-3x+16 \subset \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$ not from $y^2=x^3-3x+3\subset \Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: [Another attempt to look at an ellipctic curve over a finite field graphically](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221055/11619). As you see, that was not very illuminating either. I agree with reuns - it may be better to modify the coefficients of the curve as you may then make more points "visible". Anyway, using $[0,13)\subset\Bbb{R}$ as a model of $GF(13)$ is doomed, because it hides the facts that in this field $14=1$, $5=-8$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to show this curve in an introductory class, I would use, instead, the modified equation
$$
y^2=x^3-16x+16.\qquad(*)
$$
The connection with your curve is hopefully clear given that $16\equiv3\pmod{13}$. I simply chose to use $16$ as the rational number lying over $3$. The reason for these choices is that the resulting curve passes through several familiar looking points with integer coordinates, namely
$$(-4,\pm4),(0,\pm4),(1,\pm1),(4,\pm4),(8,\pm20)\quad\text{and}\quad(24,\pm116).$$
See the figure below where these points are show as dots (with the exception of the last pair for they were too far out).

[image]

All those twelve points show as points on your curve over $GF(13)$ when we reduce the coefficients modulo $13$. For example, the point $(-4,-4)$ corresponds to your point $(9,9)\in GF(13)^2$, and the point $(24,-116)$ to $(11,1)$ as $24\equiv11\pmod{13}$ and $-116\equiv1\pmod{13}$.

This points at a better description of the connection between the two elliptic curves. Points of this curve, call it $E_{\Bbb{R}}$, with integer coordinates become points of your curve, $E_{GF(13)}$, when we reduce the coordinates modulo $p$.

We can extend that reduction mapping to many points of $E_{\Bbb{R}}$ with *rational* coordinates. Using the chord-tangent -method we easily find that the point $Q=(161/4,-2033/8)$ is also on the curve $E_{\Bbb{R}}$. As neither denominator is a multiple of $13$, we can interpret those coordinates as elements of $GF(13)$. After all, in $GF(13)$ we have $\overline{4}\cdot\overline{10}=\overline{1}$ as well as $\overline{8}\cdot\overline{5}=\overline{1}$. So division by four can also be realized as multiplication by ten et cetera. Here
$$
\overline{161}/\overline{4}=\overline{5}\cdot\overline{10}=\overline{11}
$$
and
$$
\overline{-2033}/\overline{8}=\overline{8}/\overline{8}=\overline{1}.
$$
Therefore the point $Q$ also becomes $(\overline{11},\overline{1})$.

We encountered a phenomenon that several points with rational coordinates may become the same point when reduced modulo $p$. This always happens, if $E_{\Bbb{R}}$ has infinitely many points with rational coordinates, but that it is a more difficult question (above my paygrade to be honest).

Observe that we have noe seen the points $(5,\pm3)\in E_{GF(13)}$ as reductions at all. I don't know if they appear at all? I didn't produce too many points with rational coordinates, and I don't know whether it is gotten in the same way. Sometimes there are points of $E_{GF(p)}$ that don't come from any point on $E_{\Bbb{Q}}$. That is because some elliptic curves have very few points over $\Bbb{Q}$. Those are, again, a bit deeper questions in number theory.

Instead, I use $(5,\pm3)$ to demonstrate a different aspect of the "reduction modulo $p$" -business. We can plug in $x=5$
into $(*)$. When we do that we see that complex points $(5,\pm\sqrt{61})$ satisfy the equation $(*)$. It happens that $$61\equiv9=3^2\pmod{13}.$$
This means that, in the field $GF(13)$ we can think of $\overline{3}$ as $\sqrt{61}$. This kind of points of $E_{\Bbb{R}}$ with square roots in their coordinates then "cover" the points that were missed out by those with rational or integer coordinates.

A summary:

> There is natural mapping from $E_{\Bbb{Q}}$ to $E_{GF(p)}$. How well a curve "lifted" to reals (or, more naturally, rationals) in this way covers the points over a finite field is a more difficult question. It may miss many points of $E_{GF(p)}$ altogether. Or it can be a (infinitely) many-to-1 relation. The details of the lifting process may become hairy, and there are related, deep open questions.

Comment: With $v=x/4$ and $u=(y-4)/8$ the equation $(*)$ becomes
$$u^2+u=v^3-v,$$ which is a minimal Weierstrass model. [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/37/a/1) lists the integer points and tells that this is a rank one curve (hence with infinitely many rational points).

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to get all fourteen points coming from integer points of a suitable lift. I was elated to find with twelve of them. Admittedly I didn't try very hard, fo this was good enough for my purposes.

Comment: All, this is not really an answer to what the OP was asking. I just couldn't resist. As I played around with various lifts and found that 12 out of 14 lift, I wanted to share it.

Comment: Thanks, this really "connects the dots" for me! I don't know why it hadn't occurred to me that -3 makes no sense in GF(13). Using -16 and +16 as the coefficients for the graph does make things nicer, but as you say this may not work for all points and all curves. 

I suppose the "canonical" form of the equation in GF(13) is $y^2 = x^3 + 10x + 3$ as $-16 \equiv 10 \mod 13$?

Comment: @Neil $-3$ makes perfect sense in $GF(13)$. I tried several representative for the cosets $\overline{3}$ and $\overline{-3}$ before I settled on these choices. It was more or less a game for me :-) The choice makes no difference in $GF(13)$.